# How do I get solver tasks in ojalgo to return the correct size result

Tags: java, math, matrix, ojalgo

I am trying various implementers of SolverTask with the intent of solving A * x = b, where A is 601 x 1100 and b is 601 x 1 in my tests. So far I have tried GaussSeidelSolver and JacobiSolver, both by invoking solve(A, b) directly and, in the case of Gauss-Seidel, by invoking preallocate(601, 1100, 1) and passing the result to solve() as a third object. No matter what I do, the returned matrix is 601 x 1 rather than 1100 x 1.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't think you're doing anything wrong. (I'm guessing the iterative solvers are only tested using square matrices.) What happens if you supply a 1100 x 1 matrix/vector as the preallocated

Comment: The good news is that I get a vector of the correct dimension (with both solvers) by doing that. The bad news is that the vector contents are nonsense. With the G-S solver I get a streak of near-infinity values, a couple of infinities, a run of NaNs and a run of zeros. With the Jacobi solver, it's a run of NaNs followed by a runs of zeros. I should probably note that the system is consistent; I get correct solutions using SVD. It appears I'm barking up the wrong tree here.